# Arquillian + TestNG: How to access container managed objects in @Before/@After methods?

Tags: java, testng, jboss-arquillian

I couldn't find any satisfying solution for this problem, though other people have encountered it before...

I'd like to test a business bean which modifies *persistent* data using a dao.

The dao can be *injected* into the test methods as it is an ejb.

How to make it available in typical `@Before/@After` methods, for example to clean up the db.

Brief Example:

```
@PersistenceTest
public class MyTestClass extends Arquillian {
    @Inject private Dao dao;
    @Inject private MyBean myBean;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void cleanDB () {
        dao.remove(foo); // Currently throws NPE as dao is not injected.
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest () {
        // In a Test-method dao is available and calling cleanDB from here also 
        // works as intended....
    }
}
```

As far as I know only the Test-methods are executed in the container. Most information that I found seems to be outdated.

Is there any nice way to achieve this?

Thank you!

I'm using (managed) Wildfly 8 as app server.

Answer (score 2):

Arquillan invokes the @Before** and @After** methods twice.
Once in client mode, once in container mode.

The only solution I found so far is, that you must verify that the dao was injected before you use it like :

```
@BeforeMethod
public void cleanDB () {
    if (dao != null) {    
        dao.remove(foo);
    } 
}
```

So if you make a breakpoint and runs your code you should have 2 invokations of this method:
1st: dao is null
2nd: dao is injected

Hope that helps.

See also http://jayshaughnessy.blogspot.de/2012/11/arquillian-and-testng.html for more information.